# gimp - How to move between input using 'tab' keyboard button?

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, gimp

It is possible to move between inputs using `tab` keyboard button? Now I cannot. Do I need to set anything? I have GIMP 2.8.14 on Lubuntu 14.04.
[See the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JY6ER.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should be able to hit <kbd>tab</kbd> to move between controls (GIMP calls them widgets).
In older versions of GIMP you could configure this by going to

- `File / Preferences / Interface / Hotkeys / Dialogues / Jump to widget`

In My GIMP 2.8 the option doesn't appear to be available - but when I hit <kbd>tab</kbd> the focus moves from one control to the next.

I would try going to

- `File / Preferences / Interface /`
- then select
- `Reset keyboard shortcuts to default values`

And see if it restores tabbing for you

Comment: I reset shortcuts but without result. Normally, when I hit `tab` in GIMP 2.8 then all widgets dissapear, only opened picture is displayed.  I try to find `tab` shortbut between `keyboard shortcuts` settings but there is none such option.

Comment: If all widgets disappear, then the image has the keyboard focus - Tab is the hotkey to hide and show the docks in this case. You should file a bug with Lubuntu, they can research it and determine whether it is specific to their distro, and report it upstream if necessary